# Looping through words and adding 'a' tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wrapper, words

I am trying to write a script that would loop the words and add href link to each non-linked word.

Example:

```
<body>
something
<a href = "anything"> Blaba </a>
<p>Some words</p>
Something else
</body>
```

would be :

```
<body>
<a href= "added link" > something< /a>
<a href = "anything"> Blaba </a>
<p><a href= "added link" > Some< /a> <a href= "added link" > words< /a></p>
<a href= "added link" > Something< /a>  <a href= "added link" > else< /a> 
</body>
```

I reached the wrapper function only

```
function Replacer(x){
    var str = $(x).text();

    var words = str.split(" ");

    var inner = " ";
    var wordsLength = words.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < wordsLength; i++) {
            dict_url = 'http://' + language + '.kasahorow.org/app/d?kw='+  words[i] + '&fl='+ language +'&tl=en';
            final_line = '<a href="' + dict_url+ '" >' + words[i] + " </a>";
            inner = inner + final_line

    }

    $(x).replaceWith(inner);
}
```

it works when I work it with something like this

```
  $('p').each(function(){

      Replacer(this);

  }); :
```

But I need it with all non-linked words.

Comment: The HTML document is a tree of nodes. You should traverse this tree and check if a node is a "text node". If it is then you replace it with an anchor.

Comment: [Don't reinvent the wheel](http://padolsey.github.io/findAndReplaceDOMText/demo.html). https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText

Comment: @Vohuman Add your comment as an answer, and I'll gladly up-vote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over child nodes, replacing only in text nodes. Skip `a` nodes for obvious reasons.

```js
function ReplaceText(x)
{
   var str = x.textContent;

   var words = str.split(" ");

   var wordsLength = words.length;
   var parent = x.parentNode;
 
   for (var i = 0; i < wordsLength; ++i) {
     dict_url = 'http://lang.kasahorow.org/app/d?kw='+  words[i] + '&fl=lang&tl=en';
     var a = document.createElement('a');
     a.setAttribute('href', dict_url);
     a.innerHTML = words[i];
     parent.insertBefore(a, x);
     parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(' '), x);
    }
 
    parent.removeChild(x);
}

function Replacer(x){
    var kids = x.childNodes;
  
    for ( var j = kids.length - 1; j >= 0; --j )
      {
        if (kids[j].nodeType == 3)
          ReplaceText(kids[j]);
        else if (kids[j].tagName.toLowerCase() != "a")
          Replacer(kids[j]);
      }
  }
   

Replacer(document.body);
```

```html
something
<a href = "anything"> Blaba </a>
<p>Some words</p>
Something else
```

Comment: You have some formatting problem with the code plus a global variable leakage. The code also makes two separate links to look like one because of adding spaces after the words.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fuction makeLinks(language){  
  $(document).contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  }).replaceWith($(this).text().replace(/\b(.+)\b/, "<a href='http://"+language+".kasahorow.org/app/d?kw=$1'>$1</a>"));
}
```